# Выезжающая картинка

Tags: html, css

Надо, что-бы при входе на сайт вылезала справа картинка, через 5 секунд заезжает обратно, вот сама картинка:

[image]

Comment: CSS3 transition

Comment: CSS3 animation.

Answer (score 2):

После загрузки документа, находим блок с медведем (класс **bear**) и добавляем ему класс **bear_vis** на котором висит анимация *bear-animation*. Изначально наш медведь спрятан за пределы экрана.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var bear = document.querySelector(".bear");
    bear.classList.add("bear_vis");
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.bear {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGoNR.png);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 185px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100px;
  transition: 4s all;
}

.bear_vis {
  animation: bear-animation 5s linear;
}

 @keyframes bear-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateX(100px);
    }
    70% {
        transform: translateX(100px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bear"></div>
```

Comment: А как сделать чтоб он обратно не возращался?

Comment: @Gra1n добавить forwards в конце:  animation: bear-animation 5s linear forwards;